# running skdmanager from command-line produce a java exception

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want to build a react native app. and I need android SDK. so I downloaded command line tool and when I run sdkmanager from command-line. it produce a wired java exception. I am using windows 10

here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 72: C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ar\tests\weirdFileNames\
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.toPath(FileSystemFileOp.java:284)
        at com.android.repository.io.impl.FileSystemFileOp.isDirectory(FileSystemFileOp.java:169)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:225)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:226)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.collectPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:201)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:123)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:518)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:365)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:725)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:296)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

Comment: Which version of sdkmanager do you have? Is it up-to-date? Have you checked https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html?

Comment: Currently I have downloaded the latest version via it's official web site

Comment: Please specify the command line you used.

Comment: Also add info about any working command with sdkmanager, e.g. sdkmanager.bat --list

Comment: Your failed path looks related to nodejs installed files (modules). Maybe uninstall them before using sdkmanager?